# Function parameters max number

Tags: c, parameter-passing, stack-overflow

I did not find any limitation of count function parameters in the C99 standard and I guess it is only limited by stack size.

However I've written a simple test program to demonstrate the behavior of a function with a large count of parameters. When its about 10k, I get the following error on gcc (gcc version 4.5.3 on Cygwin):

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/../../../libcygwin.a(libcmain.o):(.text+0xa9): undefined reference to `_WinMain@16'
```

I realize that such large count of parameters is unlikely but I wonder what parameter of the compiler determines this limit?

**EDIT**

script to generate C-source

```
#!/bin/sh

num=$1

echo "" > out.c
echo "#include <stdio.h>" >> out.c

echo "int getsum( " >> out.c

i=0
while [ $i -lt $num ]
do
    ((i++))
    if [ $i -eq $num ] 
    then
        echo "int p$i )" >> out.c
    else 
        echo -ne "int p$i," >> out.c
    fi
done

echo "{" >> out.c

echo -ne "  return " >> out.c

i=0
while [ $i -lt $num ]
do
    ((i++))
        if [ $i -eq $num ]
        then
                echo "p$i;" >> out.c
        else
                echo -ne "p$i + " >> out.c
        fi
done

echo "}" >> out.c

echo "int main(){"  >> out.c
echo "printf(\"Sum of %d elements is %d\", $num, getsum(" >> out.c 

i=0
while [ $i -lt $num ]
do
        ((i++))
        if [ $i -eq $num ]
        then
                echo "$i" >> out.c
        else
                echo -ne "$i," >> out.c
        fi
done

echo "));" >> out.c

echo "return 0;}" >> out.c
gcc out.c
./a.exe
```

Comment: Care to share the code that caused this?

Comment: @Martinsh Shaiters i've wrote some sh-script to generate sources. See updt

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Standard specifies a certain minimum number which every implementation must support,

**5.2.4.1 Translation Limits**

> — 127 parameters in one function definition
>   — 127 arguments in one function call

Comment: Interesting. That's not a whole lot! I would have thought "unlimited, depending on memory size" too.

Comment: These are the *minimum acceptable limits* an implementation may impose. It's certainly allowable (and desirable) to have a larger limit or no explicit limit at all on things like this.

Comment: There is also the limit on the maximum length of a source line, 1K-something, or maybe 4K-something. The test program will likely hit this limit, too. (whatever comes first ...)

Comment: Not to mention there is a *maximum acceptable limit* imposed by the humans who have to read your code, and exceeding this limit can cause Undefined Behavior in those persons. So don't stretch it :)

Comment: @wildplasser Does "source line" mean a line that is terminated with a CR/LF, or a line that is terminated with a semicolon? The first would be a limit that is easy to avoid. The latter limit would be harder to avoid.

Comment: That's way more than it should be. I'd say the standard should cap it at 8.

Comment: @R..: It's necessary that there exist at least one possibly-contrived program that uses 127 arguments and which the compiler processes in standard-compliant fashion.  A function which ignores all 127 arguments and unconditionally returns zero would probably suffice to meet that requirement.  I don't think anything in the Standard requires that the implementation must correctly process a function that accepts 127 arguments and actually does anything with them.