# Is there a limitation of the number of Variable Arguments in C?

Tags: c

As far as I know, and could detect, the C99 document doesn't says something about this limitation.

And I would suggest, this is limited by the compiler.
But I don't know what I would have to look for, to figgure this out.

So could anyone tell me whats the limited amount of Vargs by which compiler ( or who else does give this limitiation) and where I can check this.

Comment: Since I'm not 100% sure, I'd assume as many as fit on the stack, but at some point I'd really suggest passing some struct rather than single values. :)

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.5/cpp/Implementation-limits.html doesn’t mention limitation on number of arguments so I's say is limited only by the stack

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034787/function-parameters-max-number this says 127 arguments

Comment: from a practical point of view the argument limitation should be imposed by stack size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured out what the standard says in C99 TC3 of function arguments it self.

I just found this:

> 5.2.4.1 Translation limits
>
> The implementation shall be able to translate and execute at least one program that
>   contains at least one instance of every one of the following limits:
>
> [...]
>
> — 127 arguments in one function call

I don't see a reason why the standard should specify this limitation more explicit.
So this is what I have seen so far. And it should be the only lower limitation.